# 17.10 to 18.04 upgrade problem

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04.01 and have this problem: after "fetch is complete" message, it rolls back the system and I can't continue. Can someone give me an advice?

Screenshot 1:

[image: look this photo 1]

Screenshot 2:

[image: look this photo 2]

Comment: I agree with user535733, so ensure you read that. I also find `do-release-upgrade` from the terminal is more helpful is viewing problems (when they occur).  Even if you don't understand the messages, you've got something 'concrete' to copy & paste for us to help you with! (*and we've got far more to understand your issue*)

Comment: Guys, I tried  `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and output without any problem

Comment: The `sudo apt-get update` updates your software (repo) lists , the `upgrade` performs upgrades within certain rules, `dist-upgrade` performs the same as upgrade but with fewer limitations on skipped-upgrades; but those still keep you on 17.10.  It's the `do-release-upgrade` command which will 'bump' you to 18.04, and will attempt what you mentioned in question, but provide clues we can't read because the gui in your pictures hides that info from gui-users.

Comment: If you did #1 and #3 below, then it's time to do #2. Ubuntu does not give partial credit, and #2 is the most common problem with release-upgrades.

Comment: Ok, what is correct PPA(s)? I've disabled all PPAs which unofficial and removed all packages I can, but without success

Comment: There are no 'correct' PPAs. *ALL* PPAs are unofficial (or testing), and ALL software from PPAs should be uninstalled.

Comment: @user535733, 
I've removed all I can.
This is peace of output of my `do-release-upgrade`:
`Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree`
Does it mean that system can't find updates?

Comment: Artful is EOL and [those repositories are closed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) - a completely different problem than your original question. AskUbuntu uses a Question/Answer format, and comments are intended to help you refine or improve the Question. They are not really intended for conversation. You can see that based upon your comments I have improved my answer...to your question above. Folks with multiple or complex problems, or who need conversational tutoring/training should try our sibling site http://www.ubuntuforums.org, which is not limited to our Q/A format.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for the suggestion. I've created the thread in the forum, and will appreciate if we continue there. [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401249&p=13801125#post13801125 ]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Test your network connectivity**. Ensure apt is working properly on your system, and can reach it's repositories. Ubuntu will (understandably) refuse to do a release-upgrade if it cannot download the packages. This is the most common easy-to-test and easy-to-fix problem.
2. **Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible** - uninstall all packages from unofficial (non-Ubuntu) sources and PPAs, and disable those sources. Those packages sometimes use version numbers that confuse the package management logic, blocking critical packages from being upgraded. If those critical packages are blocked, Ubuntu will (understandably) refuse to do a release-upgrade.

   This is the most common problem that new users encounter if they have (unwisely) installed a lot of PPAs and other non-Ubuntu software and no longer remember what they installed from which source. Next time, choose the source of your online instructions more judiciously - most of the software you want is *already* in the Ubuntu repositories. In complex cases, it might be easier for some users to simply backup their data and clean-install the new release of Ubuntu.
3. **NEVER release-upgrade to try to fix a mysterious problem or an unstable system**. Release-upgrades usually make those problems worse, not better. You should be able to run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` with ZERO errors before starting a release-upgrade.